# Where can I find source code for Windows commands?

Tags: windows, cmd

I've been messing around with command prompt for a few days now, but I want to have a better understanding of what's actually going on under the hood. Searching the Internet has been of no use so far, as almost all the results there will show, you the syntax of the commands, which is not I want.

Is it possible to retrieve the source code for any of the Windows commands?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Windows is closed-source.

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь Source code for some parts of Windows is open sourced. .NET is a prime example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source code for some parts of Windows is open sourced. .NET for example. Other parts of the source code are available via various programs, described [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sharedsource/). One program that I've used is [Code Center Premium](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sharedsource/code-center-premium.aspx). In this program you are assigned a smart card/PIN and use a specific URL to access the source code for the various versions of Windows. Generally only RTM (release to manufacturing) code is available on CCP (as opposed to patched versions of the code).

If you are an individual you probably won't be able to get access via any of these programs, except possibly the MVP program. But if you were an MVP you probably would already understand "what's going on under the hood" to a large extent.

As an individual I suggest the book **Windows Internals**, which you can find as a PDF on the web. Note that the book is over 1000 pages, so a huge amount of information is available within. Also, there are various examples in the book in the way of commands that control/monitor various aspects of Windows (no source code, but an explanation of how the command works)

Note that a book will be much more comprehensible than the Windows source code which if I remember correctly is well over 100,000,000 lines currently.

Note that for "vanilla" commands like COPY, DIR, etc., perusing the Win32 API  set for file & directory I/O on MSDN will yield the APIs that CMD.EXE uses. Many samples are also available on MSDN and elsewhere.

Comment: Awesome resource to Code Center Premium. Too bad the original question is off-topic!

Comment: Not off topic :/